# How to add filter subscription to log group with CDK

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm trying to add a log group subscription to an existing lambda.

```
 (cont, log_group) = self.container_for_ecr_image(build_stack.task_repo, task, 'task1')
log_group.add_subscription_filter(id="task1-subscribe", destination=??, filter_pattern="")
```

I have the function 'ARN' and name but no reference to the function.
How can I extract the function reference using CDK if I only have the function ARN?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is:
`aws_lambda.Function.from_function_arn(self, id="id", function_arn="function_arn")`

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong here - [but from looking at the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_lambda/Alias.html) it looks like the **Alias** class from Lambda might be able to "create" a reference to an existing lambda. But I'm not too sure as I'm quite new to this stuff.

It's difficult to work with existing stuff in the CDK because I think the best practice is to create everything through CloudFormation (if IaC is your goal)

Comment: Thank Jamie,
I found a way to do it:


```aws_lambda.Function.from_function_arn(self, id="id", function_arn="function_arn")```